# Scheduled reboot script for TP-Link VPN load balancer router TL-ER604W

Tags: cron, router, expect, telnet, schedule

How to schedule rebooting router model **TP-Link VPN load balancer router TL-ER604W** ?

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question; first of all , this will require that you have to connect through telnet.

Then just install  *expect* and *telent* on your Debian  GNU/linux

```
sudo apt install expect telnet
```

Then save the following script in any file name of your liking and configure it with *crontab* to schedule it.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout 5
set username "admin"
set password "myp@ssw0rd"
set enabled_password "myp@assw0rd"
spawn telnet 192.168.1.254
expect "Username:"
send "$username\r"
expect "Password:"
send "$password\r"
sleep 1
expect "TP-LINK > "
send "enable\r"
expect "Enter password:"
send "$enabled_password\r"
expect "TP-LINK # "
send "sys reboot\r"
expect "This command will reboot system, Continue? \[Y/N\]: "
send "y\r"
```